# 32-bit integer representation of unicode string

Tags: python, unicode

Try to understand unicode in Python. I am reading https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#encodings

and I don't understand in this chapter of Python Unicode "How to" why first example choosen for string representation in unicode is 8 hex characters long = 32bits since unicode code points are "only" 0x10ffff = 21bits maximum = 6 hex characters in base-16.
Could you please explain?

Comment: If you are having trouble with unicode with Python, I highly recommend you switch to Python3, unicode handling is much more easier

Comment: I suppose python2.7 will help me to understand encoding ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no 21-bit integer type (that would be 2.6 bytes, which makes no sense). There is no 24-bit integer type (3 bytes) either. The only choice would have been between 16 and 32 bits, and 16 bits is too small.

Comment: why 24-bit integer does not exist?

Comment: @FTG: Modern computers are designed to quickly handle data in sizes of powers-of-two. A byte is 8 bits, 2**3. Computers can handle 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes easily, and sometimes even larger sizes, but anything in between is more time-consuming. The architecture of the CPU and of the various levels of cache determine this.